# while using eval it show function is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onFocus="javascript:findPosY()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
eval( function findPosY(){alert("OK");});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

While executing above code, eval() function not called and alert is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does a double eval. First `eval` is used for the inline event handler (which by te way doesn't need the `javascript:` part). Next you try to `eval` within your script tag. As indicated by other answers, `eval` needs a string. But in this case `eval`ling is completely unnecessary. Your snippet should be written like this:

```
<html>
<body>
 <input type="text" onfocus="findPosY()"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function findPosY(){
      alert("OK");
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @kooilnc you are right but  js  generated dynamically as Please consider we are creating User interface based on xml.so based on xml values for example <inputtype>textbox</inputtype> means we dynamically generated <input type="text" onfocus="somemethod()" value="1" id="txt1"/> as part of this we generated some javascript code dynamically so with  html i rendered js code in UI for that i use eval method.but without eval method can we acheive this ..let me know any doubts...

Comment: @BALA: well, in that case you should make shure you're evalling a string. `eval('function findPosY(){alert("OK");}');`. See http://jsfiddle.net/58eKh/

Answer (score 2):

#### `eval()`

> Evaluates a **string** of JavaScript code...

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: @ Mr.alex as your mentioned link if is pass string through eval it is possible to attacked by malicious party. Any alternate  way what is your suggestion.

Comment: @BALA There is no reason why `eval()` would be used if you want to execute your code example. Why are you wanting to use `eval()`?

Comment: Dear alex in our project scenario as we generated dynamically all ex textbox ,etc some js script also generated dynamically as string so using innerhtml i take that string and passed over the eval.so i use eval. any alternate way for this??? is highly appreciated..

Comment: @BALA I can not understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @ alex we are generating User interface based on xml.so based on xml values for example **<inputtype>textbox</inputtype>** means we dynamically generated <input type="text" onfocus="somemethod()" value="1" id="txt1"/>  as part of this we generated some javascript code dynamically so with this html i rendered js code in UI for that i use eval method.let me know u have any doubts sir

Comment: @BALA: if I understand you correctly, and that JS is generated, you still don't need to put it inside `eval`. it'll run as soon as it's sent to the client. well..unless you mean to call the function. for that, you can add `findPosY()` at the end..

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a string to eval function:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onFocus="javascript:findPosY()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
eval( 'function findPosY(){alert("OK");}');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks farshid but using eval like above is any dangerous because third party can easily hacked code or passing virus....how to avoid it

Comment: dear damodar above code is working you check with which browser??

Comment: @BALA: so the main question is why are you using eval at all?

Comment: yes can you tell any alternate without using eval executing js code as string (mainly function is also supported)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onFocus="javascript:findPosY()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
eval('(function (){alert("OK");})()');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note the parenthesis at the end of the string being eval'd, this will call the function.

Comment: this would alert 'OK' at load time. I'm almost sure that's *not* what the OP intended.

Comment: I think this **is** what the OP needs, see his last line: "While executing above code, eval() function not called and alert is not displayed." I assume that the alert is the replacement of some code the OP needs to be executed at load time.